Google Dataform - ValueError: Protocol message WorkflowInvocation has no "workflow_config" field
I am executing dataform from Airflow with the DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator.
calls_dataform_workflow = DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator(
      task_id='calls_dataform_workflow',
      project_id="...",
      region="...",
      repository_id="...",
      workflow_invocation={
          "workflow_config": "projects/.../locations/.../repositories/..../workflowConfigs/airflow_default",
          "invocation_config": {
              "included_targets": [{
                  "database": "...",
                  "schema": "...",
                  "name": "..."
              }]
          }
      }
)

As a result of this invocation I get the error:

ValueError: Protocol message WorkflowInvocation has no "workflow_config" field.

I checked on the source code and workflow_config indeed is an attribute of WorkflowInvocation.
Also as in the API reference
Could it be because it's in beta and and is not working appropriately?
